# How to run application in different sdk versions in android

Tags: android, sdk

I am new in android development. and i have task to develop the application.

i developed an app and it's working fine in android sdk version 2.3.1 but i have to develop it with the multiple versioning. I'm not able to find the way to do this.

Please give me any clue or idea to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must modify your manifest of your app.

You could read that : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

and that : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

You must find what you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

go to `Eclipse->Android SDK &AVD Manager`. Create several AVD with Different SDk versions by doing doing `AVD Manager->new->Name->Target(the sdk version)->Create AVD ->strat` (by selecting that particular sdk version)

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml you can set the min sdk version required to use your application with: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />`

On your project properties you define on witch SKD you will build your application (2.3.1 for you).

[image]

In AVD Manager you just need to create different devices to test, you can create a device for each SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Eclipse ->Window ->Android SDK & AVD Manager. 
Create several new AVDs with different SDK versions.

Start the emulators of different SDK versions.
Now, try to run the app. It will ask to choose the emulator. Choose the one you want.